# How do I search for a user in a particular OU on a remote LDAP server?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, adlds

I would like to use the `AccountManagement` namespace introduced in .NET 3.5 to find a user and set their password.  However, the ADLDS server is not part of our company domain so I'm using `ContextType.Machine`.  When I search for the user it's never found (I suspect it's searching in the wrong container, but according to the documentation when using `ContextType.Machine` you can't specify a container).

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, "test-server", null, "username", "password")) {
    using (var u = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, "SuperAdmin")) {
        //u is always null.   :(
    }
}
```

However, I know I can find the user using plain ol' `DirectoryEntry`:

```
using (var de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://test-server:389/CN=SuperAdmin,CN=SuperUsers,OU=test-server,DC=foo,DC=bar,DC=com", "username", "password", AuthenticationTypes.Secure)) {
    //The user is found, but SetPassword fails with "The directory property cannot be found in the cache"
    de.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "foobar" });
}
```

One last thing to point out is that I can use ADSI Edit to change the password with these same credentials.  Is it possible to use the newer directory objects to perform this search?

Answer (score 0):

It's really an old question, but just recently I had to work on a similar project... I'll post the answer if anybody runs into the same issue.

The reason you cannot find the `user` using `UserPrincipal` class is that as you mentioned you're searching using `ContextType.Machine`. But in `DirectEntry` class you're just doing a simple `LDAP://` query.

Here's my solution.

I store my server information in `.config` file.

```
... 
//Server name and port
<add key ="ADLDS_Server" value="Servername:port"/> 
//Note* depending on structure container will be different for everybody
<add key ="ADLDS_Container" value="CN=Some Value, DC=some value,DC=value"/>
...
```

I then created `ADLDSUtility` class that returns `PrincipalContext` object.

```
...
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
...
public class ADLDSUtility
{
    public static ContextOptions ContextOptions = ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer | ContextOptions.Negotiate;

    public static PrincipalContext Principal
    {
        get
        {
            return new PrincipalContext(
               ContextType.ApplicationDirectory,
               ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADLDS_Server"],
               ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADLDS_Container"],
               //you can specify username and password if need to
               ContextOptions);
        }
    }
```

From there, I wrote a `method` that accepts *(username, currentPassword and newPassword)* as paramaters.

```
public void ChangePassword(string userName, string currentPassword, string newPassword)
    {
        using (PrincipalContext ctx = ADLDSUtility.Principal)
        {
            using (UserPrincipal principal = new UserPrincipal(ctx))
            {
                using (var searchUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, userName))
                {
                    if (searchUser != null)
                    {
                        searchUser.ChangePassword(currentPassword, newPassword);
                        // searchUser.SetPassword(newPassword);
                        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchUser.Guid.ToString()))
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Could not change password");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In this example, I'm searching user by `UserPrincipalName`. But we are not limited to that. We can also search user by `IdentityType.Guid` etc.

Now `searchUser` has two methods that involves password. I provided both of them.

```
//requires current and new password
searchUser.ChangePassword(currentPassword, newPassword);
//setting a password. Only requires new password.
searchUser.SetPassword(newPassword);
```

***NOTE* it's preferred to use SSL to set or change passwords.***